# plotting dataframe elements is messy and unreadable

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

Fairly new to this space and have spent several hours trying to find a solution to the following problem:

I have a dataframe with a column which lists some universities and a column which lists some values.

I wanted to show a clean line graph that shows all of the values for different unis, but the list is long and so the visualization is not that useful.

The line I used to graph:
pedigree_df.plot(x="UNI", y=["worldcat_libcount"]);

The output:
[matplotlib graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YFgDh.png)

Any suggestions for how to make this legible (i.e. zoomed out, with names on axis smalled and not overlapping) and meaningful would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hope this helps, you can add `rot`and specify by how much labels should be rotated

```
pedigree_df.plot(x="UNI", y=["worldcat_libcount"], rot=90);
```

edit: here is definition of `rot` from the documentation:

> rot : int, default None Rotation for ticks (xticks for vertical,
>   yticks for horizontal plots)

Comment: thanks! helped a lot. I think I also just need to find a new way of crunching so there aren't so many values displaying at once...